# After Upgrade to 5.10 unable to close Case

Tags: civicase

I get yellow screen with message as `One of parameters (value: 2019-02-13 00:25:00) is not of the type Timestamp` when i close the ongoing case. This use to work on 5.9.0 but recent upgrade to 5.10 stopped working. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a regression bug caused due to recent change to datetime on Activity forms. This is now fixed at [PR#13497](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13497) and should be part of 5.11 release. You can either wait for 5.11 release or apply patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/13497.patch).

Thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks @pradeep for you quick response. Will definitely try the patch.